# Data has strange format after saved to csv

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, streamwriter

My data after saved to csv has a format as show in the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my C# code.

```
UserDataDBsDataContext dataContext = new UserDataDBsDataContext();
            List<UserData> usersL = (from u in dataContext.UserDatas
                                         //where u.Id.Equals(13)
                                     select u).ToList();

 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("my_data.txt");
 string csv = String.Join(",", usersL.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());            
 writer.Write(csv);

 writer.Close();
```

Do you know what is missing or what I made wrong?

**UPDATE**: UserData.Properties:

[image]

Here I'm able to select property by property:

```
foreach (var i in usersL)
{
    writer.Write(i.Id);               
}
```

but I want to take whole object, as later then it will be uploaded to my app.

Comment: That's not a strange format. Instead of saving individual fields, you saved the result of calling `UserData.ToString()`. The default behaviour of `ToString()` is to return the type name, unless it's overriden in a class. You have to *write* the code that will return each field's value and generate the header, or use a library to do this

Comment: Do you want to create a CSV or an Excel file? A library like EPPlus can generate a real Excel sheet with a simple `sheet.LoadFromCollection(myList);`. You can create CSVs in a similar manner using a library like CSVHelper. It's not *easier* than generating an Excel file though

Comment: csv is desire for me, as then I will be loading the data

Comment: You can load Excel files too. Anyway, check CsvHelper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this:

```
Type t = typeof(UserData);
PropertyInfo[] propInfos = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);


using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("my_data.txt"))
{

    foreach(var user in usersL)
    {

        List<object> propValues = new List<object>();
        foreach(var pi in propInfos)
        {
            propValues.Add(pi.GetValue(user, null));
        }

        string csvLine = String.Join(",", propValues); 

        writer.WriteLine(csvLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Cristian, that's fine, but how to save whole object with using user.Id, user.FirstName etc....becaue if I will change my DataBase (add new column) it will be automatically reflect into c# code

Comment: I've updated the example to use reflection. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

The default `.ToString()` of objects in .NET simply writes the full name of the object (so `"LayoutMVVM.LinqToSqlClasses.UserData"` in your case). You have to overload the `.ToString()` or manually compose your data. Note that writing directly a CSV is ripe to problems... Escaping a CSV is complex (escaping `This is a "quoted" string` for example, or new lines). Search for a library that does it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

With this code

```
String.Join(",", usersL.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

you are calling the `ToString()` method from you `UserData` instances. And per default you'll get the namespace of a class when calling it's `ToString()` method. If you want to write the data in your csv file you have to get the value from your instances.

One way would be using this code

```
var lines = usersL.Select(x => string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", x.Id, x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Type))
                  .ToList();

File.WriteAllLines("my_data.txt", lines);
```

You can override the ToString() method of your UserData, too. But that is, in my opinion not a clean way because the UserData class should not know something about the way it's saved in a csv file.

/edit: using reflection

```
var properties = typeof(UserData).GetProperties();
var userValues = new List<string>();

foreach (var user in usersL)
{
    var values = new List<object>();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        object value = property.GetValue(user, null);
        values.Add(value);
    }
    userValues.Add(string.Join(",", values));
}

File.WriteAllLines("my_data.txt", userValues);
```

Comment: how can I do it? if you have any example please share, as I'm C# beginner

Comment: If you add the code of your UserData class (just the properties) I'll show you.

Comment: just added....I want to saved them all, but don't do do like "... writer.Write(i.Id);   "

Comment: Why without it? You have to define your format somewhere

Comment: format is does not matter.....column by column.....
.....whne I change my DataBase (add new column) it will be automatically reflect into c# code

Comment: You could use reflection to iterate through the properties.

Comment: also if you have some example would be great

Comment: Your welcome. Would be thankfull for an upvote and accepting my answer :)